# CXF selective service exposure

Tags: java, web-services, apache, wsdl, cxf

Can CXF services be exposed selectively to different consumers/clients?

for eg., if I have methods A, B, C, D in my WSDL, can i make only A, C available for one consumer and all the four methods for a different consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web service is just a URL and calling a WS method is a matter of sending properly formatted request wrapped in an envelope. From that description you can probably guess that you cannot hide or block some methods from certain clients. Your clients are free to send any request they want. The fact that the method does not exist in WSDL (if you manage to send different WSDL to different client) doesn't mean that method will disappear from service.

It's up to you to discover which client tries to connect and either allow or deny access to certain methods. *Allow* or *deny* are keywords here. You must implement some notion of authorization and authentication on top of your services and block some clients if they don't have permissions to certain methods.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. How do we implement authorization/authentication? can you please share a simple example?

Comment: Can we add method-wise authentication?

Comment: @user1640998: this is a broad topic. There is [tag:ws-security] specification, you can use BASIC HTTP authentication, etc. You can also add manual check on a per-method level.